# Getting the difference between 2 Observables and create 2 new observables from result

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have 2 observables:

```
this.fb.getGroupsAsObservable().subscribe(
  (list: any) => {
    this.allGroups = list;
  }
);

this.fb.getContactsGroups(this.contact).subscribe(
  (list: any) => {
    this.groupsIn = list;
  }
);
```

This works really well. But now I need to create a new Observable which is euqal to the difference between the 2 observables, which I will name 'groupsIn'. I am a bit new to rx/js, normally I would do a filter with .has() but this does not work on Observables.

Comment: Investigate the use of `pipe` with your existing observables. Then you might want to look into the rxjs version of filter.

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have something like this:

```
forkJoin(this.getGroupsAsObservable(), this.getContactsGroups(this.contact))
    .subscribe([list1, list2] => {
        // gets the difference between both returned arrays
        diffList = list1.filter((listItem) => list2.indexOf(listItem) < 0);
    });
```

This will ensure you that you'll execute your code that needs the return values of both your observables only when the observables both returned a value

Comment: Very close, I needed to use the zip operator instead because this is using firebase. This part is not working either: diffList  =list1.filter((listItem) => list2.indexOf(listItem) < 0); Because both streams are arrays of objects like this: 
0 : {contactCount: 4, id: "8WmgmLISheqDoPkmy22j", name: "Family and friends"}
1 : {contactCount: 3, id: "GBYZvMQkeCO9LuD0CGLp", name: "MKR"}
2 :{contactCount: 4, id: "rV29iiyKjXHHhD0FzZjr", name: "Players only"}

Answer (score 3):

You can join them together using `forkJoin`, and then filter them accordingly.

Assuming you are using `es6` and above, the array prototype comes with the `includes` function, which can nicely be used in conjunction with `filter`.

```
Observable.forkJoin(this.fb.getGroupsAsObservable(), this.fb.getContactsGroups(this.contact))
        .subscribe(([allGroups, groupsIn]) => {
            var difference = allGroups.filter(list => !groupsIn.includes(list));
            console.log(difference)
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

[Live working example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-apmuix)
Hope this help. As the other answers pointed out, you could you `forkJoin` or `zip` but since they return a two dimensional array, you could chained with the `Map operator`. Here my approached.

```
const getGroupsAsObservable$ = of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
const getContactsGroups$ = of([3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);
const symmetricDifference = (arry1, arry2) => (
    arry1.filter(x => !arry2.includes(x))
        .concat(arry2.filter(x => !arry1.includes(x)))
)

const diff = zip(getGroupsAsObservable$, getContactsGroups$)
    .pipe(
        map(joined => {
            const [groups, contacts] = joined;
            return symmetricDifference(groups, contacts);
        })
    );

diff.subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually sounds like you're looking for [`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest) (or maybe also [`zip`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-zip)) instead of `forkJoin`. The `combineLatest` emits when each source Observables emit at least one value and then on each emission from any of the source Observables. `forkJoin` emits just once when all source Observable complete which might not do what you want.

```
const groups$ = this.fb.getGroupsAsObservable();
const contacts$ = this.fb.getContactsGroups(this.contact);

combineLatest(groups$, contacts$, (groups, contacts) => {
  return /* calculate difference */
})
```

The `zip` operator might also an option but it emits only when all source Observables emitted the same number of items.